# Error: Minified React error #321 on deployment next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I got Error: Minified React error #321 on my next.js deployment. There is no error on dev mode. I checked with npm ls react but only one react is working. I checked react version but there is no problem.

[image: Error screenshot]

And here is my code.

```js
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Router from 'next/router';
import Welcome from '../components/navbar';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import {MDXProvider} from '@mdx-js/react';
import initialGA from '../components/analytics';
import PaginationProp from '../components/pagination';

initialGA("blog");


function Home ({posts})  {

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(3);
    const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
    
  return <div >
        
     <img className="d-none d-sm-block logo" src="/logo.png" alt="my image" />
  <div className="div1">
    
    <div className="d-none d-sm-block">
    <Welcome ></Welcome>
    </div>
    <div className="d-block d-sm-none">
    <Welcome ></Welcome>
    </div>
    
   
    <Container className="ust1">
    {currentPosts.map(posts => (
    <Row className="ust justify-content-lg-center">
    <Col lg="4" >
    <Link href={posts.slug}>
    <Container className="kart img-fluid">
    <div className="postfoto ">
    <img className="postfoto2 img-fluid" src={posts.photo} alt="my image" />
    </div>
    <p className="tarih">{posts.date}</p>
    <h4 className="butonyazı">{posts.title}</h4>
    <p className="butonyazı2"><ReactMarkdown source={posts.details} /></p>
    </Container>
    </Link>
    </Col>
    </Row> 
))}
    <Row className="justify-content-center ust5">
    <PaginationProp
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={posts.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </Row>
    </Container>




    </div>    

  

    <style global jsx>{`
.......

`}</style>

    
</div>
 
 
};


export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://..../api/posts');
  const json = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts: json.posts,
  }
}
}


export default Home;
```

I use vercel for my deployment.

[image: There is my project structure.]

Comment: Did you follow the provided link for the error? https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321 It's an invalid hook call. Have you examined the stacktrace to find where in your code a `useState` is invalid?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I follow the link and applied the steps but nothing changed. I dont know stacktrace. Can you explain?

Comment: It is all the bits in red with obfuscated/mangled names and line numbers. It's also the bundled code, so it's likely one to several large code bundles, but you can click on the links (*framwork.899f847... .js*) to view the code. I would start at `t.useState` since that is the hook, and work backwards until you hit *your* code to figure out what component it is. If you haven't already, it is highly suggested to include the [eslint-plugin0react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) as part of your project's linting. It helps catch hook issues earlier in the dev process.

Comment: @DrewReese I used eslint-plugin0react-hooks but no problem with hooks.

Comment: Are you using this website in a Monorepo?

This is not an answer, but I had a similar issue on my side and the build runs if I uncheck the `Project Settings/General/Include source files outside of the Root Directory in the Build Step.` checkbox. I don't know what's wrong yet, but it seems to hint that the build Vercel is doing introduces multiple React objects.

Comment: To followup on my comment above , we fixed the build on Vercel (after re-enabling `Include source files outside of hte Root Directory in the Build Step`) by adding

`{ "resolutions": {  "react": "16.3.1", "react-dom": "16.3.1" }}`
to the `package.json` of the monorepo.